# How to select multiple column from data base by getting column from user in .net

Tags: c#, .net, linq

I have an object in my database, i.e.  with 10 attributes.
Now I want to let the user select some of them (1 or 2 up to 10 of them) and then according by user's selection I make a list of object with the attributes selected by user
the scenario that I think about is this:

*A page with check boxes that shows the attributes(columns) of that abject then user selects each of them he needs.*

But here is my problem, how to make the selected check boxes run as query?
For example user selected col 1 , col 2, col 6 , col 10, how can I write a query responsible for user selection?
Example I wanna the meaningful phrase of this:

```
var file2 = file.Select(f => new { "attributes selected by user" }).OrderBy(what user wants)
```

Comment: Sorry, i do not really understand what you are trying to accomplish

Comment: What are you using to translate your linq query into a database call - e.g. Entity Framework or old-school linq-to-sql?

Comment: @Pleun I think I explain it clearly
imagine a table in database with 10 cols.
a user wants to print all rows of that table but not all cols,just wants to print some of them
I give user check boxes to select cols he want to print
but I don't know how to write code that select the cols that selected by user (check boxes he chosen)

Comment: @Rhumborl
Entity frame work

Comment: If its only about 10 columns and not too many rows I would not bother and Always select everything and use the checkboxes only in the display logic

Answer (score 0, accepted):

they System.Linq.Dynamic library on [Nuget](https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Linq.Dynamic/) is a way to go

```
[TestMethod]
public void StringyAndDangerous()
{
    var fakePersonDbSet = new List<Person> { new Person() { FirstName = "Some", LastName = "Guy" } }.AsQueryable();
    var attributes = new string[] { "FirstName", "LastName" };
    var selectedFields = String.Join(",", attributes);
    var exprssion = string.Format("new ({0})", selectedFields);
    var result = fakePersonDbSet.Select(exprssion, attributes).Cast<dynamic>().First();
}
```

but you loose type safety and compile time checking.  You might be better taking another approach

```
[TestMethod]
public void SlowerButSafer()
{
    var fakePersonDbSet = new List<Person> { new Person() { FirstName = "Some", LastName = "Guy" } }.AsQueryable();
    var attributes = new string[] { "FirstName", "LastName" };
    var personPropertylist = CovertToKeyValuePair(fakePersonDbSet.First())
        .Where(c=> attributes.Contains(c.Key))
         .ToArray();            
}

private IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<string, object>> CovertToKeyValuePair<T>(T @object)
{
    var result = new List<KeyValuePair<string, object>>();
    var properties = typeof (T).GetProperties();
    foreach (var property in properties)
    {
        result.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, object>(property.Name, property.GetValue(@object, null)));
    }
    return result;
}
```

you'll take a performance hit both for pulling fields from the database that you don't need and for using reflection but the code will be less error prone and you won't end up with errors for trying to select columns that don't exist.

Answer (score 0):

Use `DynamicLinq`. ([link](https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Linq.Dynamic/))

Extension methods:

```
public static T GetValue<T>(this DynamicClass dynamicObject, string propName)
{
    if (dynamicObject == null)
    {
        throw new ArgumentNullException("dynamicObject");
    }

    var type = dynamicObject.GetType();
    var props = type.GetProperties(BindingFlags.Public 
                                 | BindingFlags.Instance 
                                 | BindingFlags.FlattenHierarchy);
    var prop = props.FirstOrDefault(property => property.Name == propName);
    if (prop == null)
    {
        throw new InvalidOperationException("Specified property doesn't exist.");
    }

    return (T)prop.GetValue(dynamicObject, null);
}

public static string ToDynamicSelector(this IList<string> propNames)
{
   if (!propNames.Any()) 
       throw new ArgumentException("You need supply at least one property");
   return string.Format("new({0})", string.Join(",", propNames));
}
```

Usage:

```
using System.Linq.Dynamic;

// ..

var columns = new[] { "col1", "col2", etc };

var result = context.Files.OrderBy(file => file.Id)
                          .Select(columns.ToDynamicSelector())
                          .Cast<DynamicClass>.ToList();
```

Result will be the collecion of `DynamiClass` instances wchich columns will contain selected properties.

To get single property from `DynamicClass`:

```
var columnValue = result.First().GetValue<string>("col1");
```

If you want to get values from `IEnumerable`:

```
var list = new List<File> { File1, File2, etc.. };

var result = list.AsQueryable().Select( /* the same as above */);
```